# When Burnside's Lemma does not apply

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have a finite group *G* which acts on a set *X*. I want to establish the number of *distinct* members of a subset *Y* $\subset$ *X*, however *Y* is not closed under *G* (I think that the correct terminology here is that *Y* is not an invariant subset of *X*?), so we can't use Burnside's Lemma.

The alternative, which is to count all the orbits of *Y* under *G* is ruled out because it is computationally out of reach: |*G*| = 3,359,232, while |*Y*| = 554,191,840,696.

My general question: is there any way we can reduce the complexity of the orbit-counting problem?

Supplementary question: I see this in the Wikipedia entry for "Burnside's Lemma":

> The first step in the proof of the lemma is to re-express the sum over
>   the group elements *g* $\in$ *G* as an equivalent sum over the set of
>   elements *x* $\in$ *X*:
>
> $\sum_{g \in G}|X^g| = |\{(g,x)\in G\times X :  g.x = x\}| = \sum_{x \in X} |G_x|.$

Does this equivalence hold in general, ie would it apply to my subset *Y*, or does it only apply for invariant subsets, ie: when the Lemma itself is applicable?

My hope is that somehow I can still express the orbit-counting problem in terms of fixed points, which are computationally more accessible.

Comment: `Does this equivalence hold in general` No, it does not. If you remove a non-fixed element from $X$ then the left side won't change while the right side will. And if all your points are fixed, then the subset is invariant. All in all: it's unlikely you will find anything useful for non-invariant subsets. Also note that the problem is not even well defined for non-invariant sets. Are you interested in orbits that intersect with $Y$? Then why don't you consider the closure (under the group action) of $Y$?

Comment: I have a feeling that this is a [$XY$ problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If $Y$ is not fixed by $G$, I cannot see how you could use the $G-$action on $X$ to derive information about $Y$.

Comment: @freakish Note that non-fixed elements do not exist, since the identity fixes every element. I do however agree that it seems unlikely to extend Burnside's Lemma to subsets in general. A particular example where the "naive" extension (i.e. just replace $X$ by $Y$) does not work is: Let $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ act on $\{A,B\}$ by "swapping" for the non-trivial element and let $Y=\{A\}$. Then $1/2 \sum_{g\in G} |Y^g|=1/2$, which is not even integral. By the way, note that the equality in the question does hold in general when we replace $X$ by $Y$, since this is just set theoretical.

Comment: @Uncountable What do you mean by "the identity fixes every element"? $X^g$ may contain non-fixed elements. And the sum on the right side is over all elements of $X$.

Comment: What you may be able to do is single out that part of $Y$ which is not stable under the action. More precisely, you can write $X$ as a union of orbits under the action, and then some of those will (hopefully) be contained in $Y$. If you can then deal with each of those orbits separately, now using the action, then you might get lucky and be left with a not too large set of additional elements.

Comment: Thanks everybody! For anybody who is interested, the group in question is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2608817/a-restricted-sudoku-symmetry-group-question). *G* is the "Sudoku Symmetry Group", *X* is the set of Sudoku grids, and *Y* is the subset of "Restricted Sudoku" grids. We are trying to answer the question "how many *essentially different* R-Sudoku grids?".

Comment: @freakish In the obvious extension of the lemma, we would replace every $X$ with a $Y$, in which case the equality of the question indeed holds (but the lemma does not). What I meant by my comment was that $|X^e|=|X|$.